# AMD Phenom II 1090T CPU is overheating after GPU+PSU upgrade

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gpu, overheating, ubuntu-16.04

I am interested in GPU computing, so recently decided to get a GTX 1060 6GB oc version on my PC, but there is something going wrong with the setup or the config, because when I ask for Python multithreading under Ubuntu my CPU gets really hot.

It was quite cold before the hardware upgrade. Today it reached 70°C. Right now it's idling at 51º C and when computing it goes to more than 62º C. 
Maybe my setup is too old for the GTX 1060?

- PSU: new Corsair rm750x
- Mobo: Gigabyte GA-880GM-UD2H
- CPU: AMD Phenom II 1090T
- GPU: Gigabyte GTX 1060 oc 6GB
- SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 500GB
- RAM: Kingston 8GB hyperx 1333MHz DDRAM
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What would you actually expect? Did your CPU keep cooler with the same code before?

Comment: thank you David, already decided to go for new motherboard+cpu+cooler.. there is too much diference in 9 years of tech evolving.